# JavaScript Grid that create markup in HTML5 Web Worker

Tags: javascript, html, web, jqgrid, web-worker

I am working on Business intelligence based web dashboard, i have tried several Third party JavaScript grids namely JQGrid, ng-grid.

Problem is that when Grid try to Render with big data Object it stuck and crash the browser.

Now i am thinking to Write my own GRID using HTML5 web-worker,it will create html mark up in String from data object and then pass to main object and append in DOM.

Please write suggestion about this approach,
and name the Grid that use this approach if any..

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using pagination? If the data is really huge, it can freeze/crash a browser even with just pure HTML.

Comment: I'm afraid that webworkers won't fix your problem because the bottleneck is probably the painting of the elements in the browser window

Comment: Yes i have tried pagination, even in case of pagination Grid process the whole data object and then divide it into pages.

Comment: Bottle neck is that there is one Thread that execute JavaScript and paint,So when it process javascript with main Thread Browser Stop respond!

Comment: Could you include more details about the size of the grid which you need to create: **how many column it has? how many total rows it could have (1000, 10000, 10000000 etc)?** how you tried to filled the grid? Which `datatype` you used? If you made some attempts you should include JavaScript code which creates the grid and filled the data. I suppose that you can solve the performance problem just using *another jqGrid options* and using *local* paging of data.

Comment: You can use a scroll on your grid and bring data when you move it. But... paging its the Best solution i  guess.

Comment: @Oleg data Fetch from Data-ware house and number of column and rows depends on user and its defined metadata,there could be N(1-200000) rows and M columns(1-100).App use JSON data type and  create model of grid from meta data and pass data Object to JQgrid.

Comment: @Adnan: Do you have implemented **server side paging, sorting and filtering**? It has no sense to return all 200000*100 items and try to show all for the user. The user should be just able to **filter** the data based on some criteria, sort the results and then see the first page of resulting data with the possibility to go to next pages. So the user should be able *to analyse* the 200000*100 items of data.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most performant grids for huge amounts of data is [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid).
If you are to write your own you should ensure you avoid paints, like comments mention, and use a virtual scroll if you really have a *lot* of rows (100k+++).

I once started writing my own grid and I can guarantee you that making it performant for lots of data while keeping it usable is not exactly an easy job :)